# Is there a Click Handler for Shell Extension

Tags: c++, windows, com, shell-extensions

After going through [MSDN Shell Extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff468984(v=VS.85).aspx) I am not quite sure if I can extend the behaviour of Shell Click or Click Event of explorer. Any suggestion or Code Snipet, article or Walk through?

Comment: Are you talking about a context menu shell extension?

Comment: @humbagumba, I am talking about he Normal Click Event. Letz Say the click event while we open a Folder

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no such possibility. That would make the shell too vulnerable. Imagine all the malware that exploits this functionality.

If you want to capture the click event, there is no easy way. You may [SetWindowsHookEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644990%28VS.85%29.aspx) and monitor/capture mouse messages for all windows of CabinetWClass and/or DirectUIHWND class. You may inject your code to explorer.exe's process and intercept messages from there. Here's a snippet of [injecting a dll into a process](http://www.dreamincode.net/code/snippet407.htm).