# Send File Programmability in C#

Tags: c#, .net, windows, filesystems, sendfile

How would you go about detecting, blocking, or just in general referring to the Send File operation you can do to any file/folder on Windows. What exactly is happening when a send file happens and is there any kind of built in programmability in .NET or is it something similar to how doing a move works(It gets deleted first and then created in the new location.)

I just want to know if there is any way to detect when a Send File happens or what windows does with the file/folder when a send file is executed.

Comment: Wouldn't you check the handler for 'Send File' in the registry?

Comment: "It gets deleted first and then created in the new location". I ***really*** hope any move routine doesn't do this. What happens in a power cut?

Comment: I tried answering your question basically.. but I think you need to be much more specific about what you are trying to accomplish for a real answer

Comment: you are speaking of the menu that comes up when you right click on a file/folder in explorer?

Comment: So I guess to simply put what I am attempting to accomplish: I am trying to block the Send To a path/folder etc

Answer (score 0):

If you are speaking of the "Send To" context menu when you right-click on a file/folder, that is the result of a shell extension handler.  Pretty sure there's now way to intercept those:
[Is there a Click Handler for Shell Extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3476939/is-there-a-click-handler-for-shell-extension)

MS documentation on registering/creating your own handers is below:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144067%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144110%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

I presume that if you select "Send To" and pick a folder/drive, then it would do a standard move or copy (depending on if it is the same drive or not).  As mentioned by Alan, you can use a FileSystemWatcher to try and monitor specific files/directories, but be careful being over broad with what you are watching, because there are limitations on how fast FSW can receive events, meaning if you watch to much you *will* miss events.  Another option if you absolutely must see the file move would be to hook into the Change Journal, but that gets really ugly.

Comment: Does that mean I have no way to deal with it? How would one go about blocking Send To's to a removable device or part of the drive?

Comment: @JBeck are you only wanting to block the Send To, or are you blocking them from using all methods of copying to said locations?

Comment: I want to block the Send To

Comment: I don't think it's going to be possible to just block the send to.  If you could block all access you could use ACL's to do it.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to stop someone from moving or copying a file, you would have to alter its permissions for read and/or modify to exclude the user.

There is a [FileSystemWatcher class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) that may help you detect changes to the file system. Also, the [File Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.move.aspx) has a static method for Move and other file operations. You may look into the System.IO namespace

When you move a file, it doesn't usually get recreated and deleted (if they are on the same device). Usually its location is just modified. (hence it happens almost instantly even on large files)

Comment: ...only if they share the same drive.

Comment: @spender That is why I said "usually" but I should probably update that to clarify

Comment: I am aware of the FileSystemWatcher class, and I am not concerned with moves right now or any of the other subscribed event-handlers available to FileSystemWatcher. I am concerned with how to handle a Send To within the context menu of any file/folder.